# ContentControl BackGround,BorderBrush Wont be Changed in Uwp

Tags: c#, uwp

```
ContentControl contentControl = new ContentControl();
StackPanel stackPanel = new StackPanel();
stackPanel.Height = 50;
stackPanel.Width = 100;
//stackPanel.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
contentControl.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
contentControl.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.BlanchedAlmond);
contentControl.BorderThickness = new Thickness(5);
contentControl.Content = stackPanel;
```

When i set background for stackpanel it works,but it doesnt work for contentcontrol..
i need contentcontrol background.!!

Answer (score 1):

As @Joey said, `ContentControl` internally relies on `ContentPresenter` to work, but the Background property set in `ContentControl` is not passed to the internal `ContentPresenter`. So we need to override the default style.

Add these code to `App.xaml`:

```xml
<Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                      Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                                      ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                      VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

After that you can set the background color for `ContentControl`.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks; I couldn't really elaborate more since I've never used UWP and more or less hoped that it works the same as WPF.

Answer (score 0):

What does the control template look like for your `ContentControl`? My guess would be that it's just a single `ContentPresenter` and nothing else. Especially nothing that has a `TemplateBinding` to the properties you're trying to change. Control properties don't magically have an effect, unless the control's template incorporates them.

Something like the following control template would probably work in your case:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
  <Border BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                      Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"/>
  </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: i cannt understand ,can you explain it briefly?

Comment: @PremKumarShanmugam: This is fairly basic knowledge how templating and binding in WPF and UWP work. That's hard to describe _briefly_ since it's a fairly major and important concept. You could read an introduction [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/control-templates). And I'm fairly certain that ContentControl's default control template is just a ContentPresenter, without a border that might have template bindings to the Background or BorderBrush property.